# z-index of image inside a element with z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a problem with the z-index of my image. I have a list and every list item has an image. Now i want to have the image inside a list item show above the other list items.

```
<li style="position: relative; z-index:9;">
 <img src="/" />
</li>
<li style="position: relative; z-index:8;">
 <img src="/" style="position: absolute; z-index:999;" />
</li>
```

Comment: I don't see a real question here? What is the problem you're experiencing? Where goes it wrong? What bit of codes doesn't work like it should work and most of all: what are you expecting?

Comment: The first li item is still above the image from the second li item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` inherits from the parent element, so whatever z-index you have on the `UL` will be applied to the `LI`s and therefore onto the `img`s. You'll have to use another element positioned on top of the `LI` with the image you want to cover.